# How to get Youtube page's username Using Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find the page's username through the Youtube API (******@pages.plusgoogle.com). I'm not getting this information through a request like: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true

What should I do?

PS: I'm using the PHP Library.

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Comment: @alfasin I did try that. I get a lot of other info like channel id and title, ... but not the page's username.

Comment: Because of this, i am forced to have my app read a config file having both  username mapped to channelId.   I wish i only needed the channelId by itself.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to get the `/c/username` or the `/user/username` via the YouTube API at this moment.

Comment: Thanks @janykste, is there a work around? Using other APIs?

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking everywhere.   They should say that on their page.